# Create a coffeescript to access config.ini file

Tags: coffeescript, config

i am trying to use config.ini in an existing coffeescript.
this is my config.ini

```
[env]
RUNNING_ENV = 'dev'
[dev]
security="no"
priority="P2"
[prod]
security="yes"
priority="P1"
```

Please assist me on creating a coffee file which can read these config data . I am a python deeveloper and i am new to coffee script

Answer (score 0):

`config.ini` aren't usually used in node projects.

There are packages (like [ini-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ini-config)) which can parse a `config.ini` file and make it's values accessible in your code.

Instead I would just use environment variables which are automatically accessible under `process.env` in a node (in this case written in coffeescript) project.

You might like to use the [`dot-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dot-env) package which is a common way of organising environment variables. Here is a good [blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/working-with-environment-variables-in-node-js-html) on the topic.